# При выводе данных из БД MSSQL при помощи php ошибка: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach'(T_FOREACH)

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, mpdf

Добрый день!
Не получается вывести данные, ошибка:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach'(T_FOREACH)
```

Ошибка на 99 строке. Если быть точнее то здесь:

```
. foreach($items as $r2 => $value) { "".iconv("windows-1251", "utf-8",$r2['TITLE']).""
```

Помогите разобраться.Весь код:

```
<?php

        //подключение к серверу БД 
       class db {

        public function __construct()
        {
            global $dbh;
            if (!is_null($dbh)) return;
            $dbh = mssql_Pconnect('server', 'SMViewer', 'password') or die('Не могу подключится к Базе данных');
            mssql_select_db('SM7',$dbh) or die('Не могу выбрать базу данных');        
        }   


        public function select_list($query)
        {
            $q = mssql_query($query);
            if (!$q) return null;
            $ret = array();
            while ($row [] = mssql_fetch_array($q, MSSQL_ASSOC)) {
                array_push($ret, $row);
            }
            mssql_free_result($q);
            return $ret;
        }

       }

    $db = new db();
    //Select the contacts SM (СУЭ) you want to show in your PDF file
    $query = 'SELECT 
                                        a1.LOCATION_NAME, 
                                        a1.LOCATION_CODE, 
                                        a1.CITY, 
                                        a1.EMAIL, 
                                        c1.DEPT_NAME,
                                        c1.LOCATION,
                                        c1.EMAIL AS C_MAIL,
                                        c1.ACTIVE,
                                        c1.FULL_NAME,
                                        c1.TITLE,
                                        c1.CONTACT_PHONE,
                                        c1.EXTENSION,
                                        c1.ROOM
                                FROM
                                        CONTCTSM1 c1
                                INNER JOIN
                                        DEPTM1 b1 ON b1.DEPT_NAME=c1.DEPT_NAME
                                INNER JOIN
                                        LOCM1 a1 ON a1.LOCATION_CODE=c1.LOCATION';


    $row = $db->select_list($query);

        if(count($row)) {
            $lorem = '';

                foreach($row as $r => $items) {
                                $loremed         .= '<h4>'
                                            . "".iconv("windows-1251", "utf-8",$r['DEPT_NAME']).""
                                            . '</h4><table class="bpmTopicC">
        <thead>
            <tr class="headerrow">
                <th>Должность</th>
                <td>
                <p>ФИО</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                Номер ВТС
                </td>
                <td>
                Городской номер
                </td>
                <td>
                Номер кабинета
                </td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr class="footerrow">
                <th>Должность</th>
                <td>
                <p>ФИО</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                Номер ВТС
                </td>
                <td>
                Городской номер
                </td>
                <td>
                Номер кабинета
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>'
                . foreach($items as $r2 => $value) { "".iconv("windows-1251", "utf-8",$r['TITLE']).""
                . '</th>
                <td>'
                . "".iconv("windows-1251", "utf-8",$r['FULL_NAME']).""
                . '</td>
                <td>'
                . "".iconv("windows-1251", "utf-8",$r['EXTENSION']).""
                . '</td>
                <td>'
                . "".iconv("windows-1251", "utf-8",$r['CONTACT_PHONE'])."" 
                .'</td>
                <td>'
                . "".iconv("windows-1251", "utf-8",$r['ROOM']).""
                . '</td>'
                . }
            . '</tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>';

    $lorem = $loremed;
                                            }

                                            } else {}




    //==============================================================
    //==============================================================
    //==============================================================
    //$lorem2 = '';

    $html = '
    <!-- defines the headers/footers -->

    <!--mpdf

    <htmlpageheader name="myHTMLHeader">
    <div style="text-align: right; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; font-family: serif; font-size: 8pt;">Зюзик</div>
    </htmlpageheader>

    <htmlpageheader name="myHTMLHeaderEven">
    <div style="text-align: left; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; font-family: serif; font-size: 8pt;">Even Header</div>
    </htmlpageheader>

    <htmlpagefooter name="myHTMLFooter">
    <table width="100%" style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; vertical-align: top; font-family: sans; font-size: 8pt;"><tr>
    <td width="33%">{DATE Y-m-d}</td>
    <td width="33%" align="center"><span style="font-size:12pt;">{PAGENO}</span></td>
    <td width="33%" style="text-align: right;">Телефонный справочник</td>
    </tr></table>
    </htmlpagefooter>

    <htmlpagefooter name="myHTMLFooterEven">
    <table width="100%" style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; vertical-align: top; font-family: sans; font-size: 8pt;"><tr>
    <td width="33%">Even Footer</td>
    <td width="33%" align="center"><span style="font-size:12pt;">{PAGENO}</span></td>
    <td width="33%" style="text-align: right;">{DATE Y-m-d}</td>
    </tr></table>
    </htmlpagefooter>


    <htmlpageheader name="tocHTMLHeader">
    <div style="text-align: right; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; font-family: serif; font-size: 8pt;">Зюзик</div>
    </htmlpageheader>

    <htmlpageheader name="tocHTMLHeaderEven">
    <div style="text-align: left; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; font-family: serif; font-size: 8pt;">ToC Even Header</div>
    </htmlpageheader>

    <htmlpagefooter name="tocHTMLFooter">
    <table width="100%" style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; vertical-align: top; font-family: sans; font-size: 8pt;"><tr>
    <td width="33%">{DATE Y-m-d}</td>
    <td width="33%" align="center"><span style="font-size:12pt;">{PAGENO}</span></td>
    <td width="33%" style="text-align: right;">Телефонный справочник</td>
    </tr></table>
    </htmlpagefooter>

    <htmlpagefooter name="tocHTMLFooterEven">
    <table width="100%" style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; vertical-align: top; font-family: sans; font-size: 8pt;"><tr>
    <td width="33%">ToC Even Footer</td>
    <td width="33%" align="center"><span style="font-size:12pt;">{PAGENO}</span></td>
    <td width="33%" style="text-align: right;">{DATE Y-m-d}</td>
    </tr></table>
    </htmlpagefooter>

    mpdf-->


    <h1>Зюзик</h1>
    <h2>Телефонный справочник</h2>

    <!-- set the headers/footers - they will occur from here on in the document -->
    <tocpagebreak paging="on" links="on" toc-odd-header-name="html_tocHTMLHeader" toc-even-header-name="html_tocHTMLHeaderEven" toc-odd-footer-name="html_tocHTMLFooter" toc-even-footer-name="html_tocHTMLFooterEven" toc-odd-header-value="on" toc-even-header-value="on" toc-odd-footer-value="on" toc-even-footer-value="on" toc-preHTML="&lt;h2&gt;СОДЕРЖАНИЕ&lt;/h2&gt;" toc-bookmarkText="Content list" resetpagenum="1" pagenumstyle="" odd-header-name="html_myHTMLHeader" odd-header-value="on" even-header-name="html_myHTMLHeaderEven" even-header-value="ON" odd-footer-name="html_myHTMLFooter" odd-footer-value="on" even-footer-name="html_myHTMLFooterEven" even-footer-value="on" outdent="2em" />

    ';

    //==============================================================
    include("mpdf.php");

    $mpdf=new mPDF('c','A4','','',32,25,27,25,16,13); 

    $mpdf->mirrorMargins = 1;

    $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage','two');$mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8');
    $mpdf->ignore_invalid_utf8 = false;$mpdf->SetAutoFont(AUTOFONT_ALL);
    // LOAD a stylesheet
    $stylesheet = file_get_contents('mpdfstyleA4.css');
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);    // The parameter 1 tells that this is css/style only and no body/html/text

    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);

    // Alternative ways to mark ToC entries and Bookmarks
    // This will automatically generate entries from the <h4> tag
    $mpdf->h2toc = array('H4'=>0);
    $mpdf->h2bookmarks = array('H4'=>0);

    //==============================================================
    // CONTENT
    for ($j = 1; $j<2; $j++) { 
       //if ($j==2) $mpdf->WriteHTML('<pagebreak resetpagenum="0" pagenumstyle="a" />',2);
       //if ($j==3) $mpdf->WriteHTML('<pagebreak resetpagenum="1" pagenumstyle="I" />',2);
       //if ($j==4) $mpdf->WriteHTML('<pagebreak resetpagenum="0" pagenumstyle="i" />',1);
       //if ($j==1) $mpdf->WriteHTML('<pagebreak resetpagenum="0" pagenumstyle="1" />',1);
       //if ($j==6) $mpdf->WriteHTML('<pagebreak resetpagenum="1" pagenumstyle="1" type="NEXT-ODD" /><div style="color:#AA0000">ODD</div>',2);
       for ($x = 1; $x<2; $x++) {

        // Alternative way to mark ToC entries and Bookmarks manually
    //$mpdf->WriteHTML('<h4>Section '.$j.'.'.'<bookmark content="Section '.$j.'.'.$x.'" level="0" /><tocentry content="Section '.$j.'.'.$x.'" level="0" /></h4>',2);

        // Using Automatic generation from <h4> tag
        //$mpdf->WriteHTML('<h4>'.$lorem2.'</h4>',2);

        $html = '';
        // Split $lorem into words
        $words = preg_split('/([\s,\.]+)/',$lorem,-1,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
        foreach($words as $i => $e) {
           if($i%2==0) {
            $y =  rand(1,10);   // every tenth word
            if (preg_match('/^[а-яА-Я]{4,99}$/',$e) && ($y > 8)) {
                // If it is just a word use it as an index entry
                $content = ucfirst(trim($e));
                $html .= '<indexentry content="'.$content.'" />';
                $html .= '<i>'.$e . '</i>';
            }
            else { $html .= $e; }
           }
           else { $html .= $e; }
        }
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
       }
    }
    //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    // INDEX


    $mpdf->Output();
    exit;
    //==============================================================
    //==============================================================


    ?>
```

Выполнил  print_r($row); :

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [DEPT_NAME] => Отдел №1 
                       [LOCATION_NAME] => 19 регион 
[LOCATION_CODE] => 19                                                                                                                                                                                          [LOCATION] => 19    
[C_MAIL] => test@mail.ru 
[ACTIVE] => f 
[FULL_NAME] => Иванов Иван Иванович 
[TITLE] => профессор 
[CONTACT_PHONE] => (391)2-22-22-22 
[EXTENSION] => 0186 0001 
[ROOM] => 6-05 ) 
[1] => Array ( [DEPT_NAME] => Отдел №1 
[LOCATION_NAME] => 19 регион 
[LOCATION_CODE] => 19                                                                                                                                                                                          [LOCATION] => 19    
[C_MAIL] => test@mail.ru 
[ACTIVE] => f 
[FULL_NAME] => Иванов Иван Иванович 
[TITLE] => профессор 
[CONTACT_PHONE] => (391)2-22-22-22 
[EXTENSION] => 0186 0001 
[ROOM] => 6-05 ) 
[2] => Array ( [DEPT_NAME] => Отдел №3 
[LOCATION_NAME] => 19 регион 
[LOCATION_CODE] => 19                                                                                                                                                                                          [LOCATION] => 19    
[C_MAIL] => test@mail.ru 
[ACTIVE] => f 
[FULL_NAME] => Иванов Иван Иванович 
[TITLE] => профессор 
[CONTACT_PHONE] => (391)2-22-22-22 
[EXTENSION] => 0186 0001 
[ROOM] => 6-05) 
....
```

Мне нужно привести к виду:

```
> Наименование подразделения №1
> 
> ФИО Номер телефона ВТС номер комнаты
> ....
> ФИО Номер телефона ВТС номер комнаты

> Наименование подразделения №2
> 
> ФИО Номер телефона ВТС номер комнаты
> ....
> ФИО Номер телефона ВТС номер комнаты
```

Comment: Конструкция `. foreach // ...` (обратите внимание на точку) ситаксически неверна. Вопрос - ни о чем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я даже не знаю, почему вы полагаете, что это должно работать.
Поменяйте фрагмент с `foreach($items as $r2 => $value)` на это:

```
<tr><th>';
foreach($items as $r2 => $value) {
    $loremed .= iconv("windows-1251", "utf-8",$r['TITLE'])
        . '</th><td>'
        . iconv("windows-1251", "utf-8",$r['FULL_NAME'])
        . '</td><td>'
        . iconv("windows-1251", "utf-8",$r['EXTENSION'])
        . '</td><td>'
        . iconv("windows-1251", "utf-8",$r['CONTACT_PHONE'])
        .'</td><td>'
        . iconv("windows-1251", "utf-8",$r['ROOM'])
        . '</td>';
}
$loremed .= '</tr>
```

Comment: Ошибка пропала. Спасибо, но теперь результат белый экран. Не подскажите в чем может быть проблема. У меня есть подозрение, что я не правильно полученный массив $row использую в двойном foreach. Мне необходимо вывести информацию из БД: Сначала наименование подразделения, затем всех сотрудников этого подразделения. И так с каждым подразделением. Все это необходимо вывести на одной странице.

Comment: @intertex, вполне вероятно, что вы неправильно обрабатываете массив $row, но я не знаю, что содержится в этом массиве, поэтому на данном этапе вряд ли чем-то смогу помочь.

Comment: Посмотрите пожалуйста, я выложил полученный массив.

Comment: @intertex, в цикле `foreach($row as $r => $items)` переменная `$r` содержит лишь идентификатор, а вот `$items` содержит ассоциативный массив. Таким образом, вместо `$r['DEPT_NAME']` и тому подобного нужно использовать `$items['DEPT_NAME']`. Второй цикл `foreach($items as $r2 => $value)` вообще не имеет смысла. Просто также выводите нужные значения без всякого цикла: `$items['TITLE']` и т. д. Дальше уже самостоятельно разберётесь.

Comment: Посмотрите я добавил к описанию, к какому виду мне нужно привести.

Comment: Я указал вам на ошибки и объяснил, как выводить информацию из имеющегося у вас массива. Дальше уже вам карты в руки. За готовым решением можете обратиться к фрилансерам.

Comment: Спасибо, а можете посоветовать что конкретно почитать по данной тематики?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50017/discussion-between-intertex-and-pyramidhead).

Comment: Давно хотел написать - спасибо еще раз! Не понял сначала ваш комментарий. Сейчас разобрался как это сделать:)